# In iOS 5, how can I fix a width issue with a Custom Design I want to use for a TabBar. Please see Image

Tags: ios5, custom-controls, tabbar, uiappearance

I have the following code in my App Delegate in order to change the appearance of my Tab Bar:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBar.png"]];
```

However, the result is not what is intended!

[a busy cat http://www.nashmexico.com/developerDocs/TabBarProblem.png](http://www.nashmexico.com/developerDocs/TabBarProblem.png)

Why is the left corner of the image not complete. I have tried changing the image size and the result is the same.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

your code to set the tabbar image is correct.

Double check the dimensions of your image, they should be like this:

low res: 320 x 48  72pixels/inch  RCB  no Alpha Channel
 high res: 640 x 96 (same)

In this example you provided, is the tabbar contained in any other controller?  The tabbar doesn't always play nice with other controllers so that is something else to watch for.